# Symbolic manipulation with unevaluated sums

Tags: symbolic

If I have two expressions with sums in them, like this:

$$\begin{align*}
b&=\frac{\sum_{i} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i -\bar{y})}{\sum_{i}(x_i -\bar{x})^2}\\
r&=\frac{\sum_{i} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i -\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i}(x_i -\bar{x})^2\sum_{i}(y_i -\bar{y})^2}}
\end{align*}$$

and I wanted to produce a simplified expression of $\frac{b}{r}$, how would I do it? The problem is the sums. It seems Mathematica doesn't like the unspecified, unevaluated sums.

**Edit:** I was expecting to end up with something like this:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i}(y_i -\bar{y})^2}{\sum_{i}(x_i -\bar{x})^2}}$$

I've been playing around with `Expand`, `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`. There may just be a way to apply it that I'm missing.

Comment: Please post your Mma code for the sums

Comment: `(Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - OverBar[x]) (Subscript[y, i] - OverBar[y]), 
    i]/Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - OverBar[x])^2, 
    i])/(Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - OverBar[x]) (Subscript[y, i] - 
       OverBar[y]), i]/
   Sqrt[Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - OverBar[x])^2, 
      i] Sum[(Subscript[y, i] - OverBar[y])^2, i]])` works on my end...

Comment: @J.M. Overbar here is `Mean[ ]`.

Comment: @Verde, Yes I'm well aware of how linear regressions are derived, but since `Mean[]` doesn't know how to handle something that isn't explicitly a list...

Comment: @J.M. That was just in case you were a chemist :D

Comment: @Verde, I *am* a chemist, you insensitive clod! ;P

Comment: @J.M. Really? Another clue I can add to my little black book...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Do you take notes of _all_ embarrassing confessions?

Comment: @Verde I have a file on you too.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks god! I am getting so perfect these days that I am afraid of forgetting my life as a  mere mortal being. Your notes will be useful for my autobiography.

Comment: @verde There are lots of sausages in there.

Comment: [This Link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3336/) can also be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The absence of a terminal $n$ in the sums suggests you are looking for a combination of symbolic reduction and typography.  Let's separate the two, then, by using symbols for the sums, performing the reduction, and then replacing the symbols by whatever we like:

[image: MMA screen shot]

Comment: Or, one can use `PowerExpand[]`...

Comment: @J.M. Interestingly (but understandably), using `PowerExpand` without explicit assumptions yields a different answer: the square roots are no longer distributed over the quotient.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a completely symbolic manipulation:

```
ClearAll[x, y, xMean, yMean, n];

varianceX = Sum[(x[i] - xMean)^2, {i, n}]
```

> $\sum _i^n (x(i)-\text{xMean})^2$

```
varianceY = Sum[(y[i] - yMean)^2, {i, n}]
```

> $\sum _i^n (y(i)-\text{yMean})^2$

```
coVariance = Sum[(x[i] - xMean) (y[i] - yMean), {i, n}]
```

> $\sum _i^n (x(i)-\text{xMean}) (y(i)-\text{yMean})$

```
b = coVariance/varianceX;

r = coVariance/Sqrt[varianceX varianceY];

b/r /. {Sqrt[a_ b_] :> Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b]}
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\sum _i^n (y(i)-\text{yMean})^2}}{\sqrt{\sum _i^n(x(i)-\text{xMean})^2}}$

All I had to do in order to help *Mathematica* get to the simplified result is to state the rule `Sqrt[a_ b_] :> Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b]`.